# Java Email Validation for UTF

Tags: java, regex, validation, email-validation

I need to make sure email is valid . And also I need to check that there is no weired UTF charactes in it .  I am dont with validating it for validation with regular expression

```
^(([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5}){1,25})+([;.](([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5}){1,25})+)*$
```

But how do I check it for UTF ?

Thanks

Comment: I don’t see anything in that regular expression that could match any weird characters. You’re always doing `a-z`, etc., not `.` or anything.

Comment: UTF is valid for email addresses. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Internationalization

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to make sure it's valid w.r.t. [RFC 5335 section 4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5335#section-4.1)?

If so, you can only check that a `byte[]` is valid UTF-8.  It doesn't make sense to try to verify a sequence of UTF-16 code units (Java `char`s) or code-points is valid UTF-8 since UTF-8 is a byte-string to codepoint-string mapping and UTF-16 is a mapping from code-units->[unicode-scalar-values](http://unicode.org/glossary/#unicode_scalar_value).  Section 3.9 of ["Unicode Encoding Forms"](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.0.0/ch03.pdf#G7404) explains all this.

The best way to tell whether a `byte[]` is a well formed UTF-8 sequence is to use one of the built in decoders, e.g. [`StandardCharsets.UTF8`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html#UTF_8) or the Guava equivalent `Charsets.UTF8`.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to make sure there are only ASCII characters in your email address, you can use that pattern:

```
"[^\\x00-\\x7F]"
```

It will mach any non-ascii character.